Why does my pilot go out when button released? The thermocouple is cleaned, tested and acknowledged by correct status blink
The pilot light on my water heater has a healthy flame so long as I'm holding down the button in the pilot position, but goes out immediately when I release the knob (even after several minutes of holding knob in).  I already eliminated the thermocouple as a problem by removing, cleaning, and testing it (voltmeter showed in excess of 35 mV when flame heat was applied).  And furthermore the control unit on the heater shows a single blink while I'm holding the button in and the pilot is lit - meaning that the control unit acknowledges the pilot is lit.  So it's receiving the signal it needs from the thermocouple.  What other things can I check for?
[And I must add one more thing - the control unit indicator flash is supposed to "have a 1-second duration" - but the single blink I'm getting is actually just a quick flash or blink.  Nothing close to 1 second duration.  So ... not sure if that is significant or not.]

Do you know wht the pilot light went out? Have you ever had to light the pilot light before? Is the thermocouple correctly positioned and there isn't any wind blowing the flame to the wrong place at an unfortunate time?

I think blink is normal, at least that's all I've noticed before...it goes out immediately when you let off pushing in the knob?

I'm curious. The new and old one has same voltage generated? You can google it for other ideas...

If it's supposed to be 1 second but it's only the briefest of flash, how does that verify that it's good? (Hint: it doesn't!)
If all is good with the flame and thermocouple positioning, the problem can only be the thermocouple or the gas valve itself that's bad (or EEK! the control board if there is one). I'd much rather buy and install a new thermocouple to see if it fixes the problem than buy a new gas valve or anything else.
If the thermocouple does not fix the problem, then you have a spare, which is a good idea anyway.

This.  Exactly this.  It will take you less time to put in a new thermocouple than it did to ask this question.  If you call a plumber, the first thing he'll do before he even attempts to analyze the problem, is change the thermocouple.    I know this from bitter experience.  I spent days in exactly your situation.  I bought a better meter.   I had to understand it.  I still don't.  But I convinced myself there's nothing wrong with the thermocouple so I paid a guy $350 to come out, and he just changed it. One screw.

@rogerdpack There's no notice to the OP of comments on answers, so best to ask this on the original question.

Not sure why my last reply was deleted.  I shared there that I did in fact replace not just the thermocouple, but the entire thermopile assembly.  It still does the same thing as described in my original post.  Sorry that it's taken me a while to get back or respond to other questions here - turns out I do have life and work apart from my hot water heater problems, and cold showers for the moment are just yet another discipline in life.
To answer Andrew Morton's query - no, I don't know why it went out originally.  But I presume the answer to that would be the same as whatever problem is preventing it from staying lit now (which isn't the wind).  Thanks, Rogerd, for your observation that the blink may be normal.  At this point, I'm just planning on getting a whole new water heater.  One last piece of info that I never shared here is that the existing unit is 13 years old!  (Which I'm told is already a pretty good run for any heater - even a well-cared for one that's been flushed regularly, etc.)  So perhaps the writing was on the wall anyway.  But we must have pretty good water here, because this heater still looks clean (relatively free of corrosion - at least from what I can see on pipes on the outside) for being the age that it is.  Of course I don't know what's on its insides.  I only know it was working well before the pilot started having these problems.  Thanks everyone!
[Added edit if there is little patience for comments or clarifications on these forums - but only solution only.  Here was the solution that worked:  Entirely new hot water heater.  Replacing the entire control unit / gas valve didn't seem to be a prudent move for me on a 13 year old heater.  But I learned a lot at least trying to fix it before jumping toward replacement.  Thanks again for help.]

This is a comment, not a solution.
